# Confusing TypeScript error using generic types

Tags: typescript

I have a setup like this:

```
export interface IListItem<TData = any> {
  id: string;
  isNew: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
  data: TData;
}

export interface IListStore<TItem> {
  allowAddNew: boolean;
  allowDelete: boolean;
  items: IListItem<TItem>[];
}

export abstract class ListStore<TItem extends any, TState extends IListStore<TItem>> {

  public state: TState;

  public setState(newState: Partial<TState>): void {

  }

  public myMethod(): void {
    const items: IListItem<TItem>[] = [];
    this.setState({             // error on
      items,                    // these three
    });                         // lines
  }

}
```

But I get this error around the `setState` method call in `myMethod`:

```
Argument of type '{ items: IListItem<TItem>[]; }' is not assignable to
parameter of type 'Partial<TState>'.
```

Which is odd because it seems a perfectly correct assignment to me?

Using VS Code v1.24.1 and TypeScript v2.9.1.

Comment: Go on the setState() definition to see the argument type. And let me know.

Comment: You mean like this: `(method) ListStore<TItem extends any, TState extends IListStore<TItem>>.setState(newState: Partial<TState>): void`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of mapped types with generic parameters and you can read why the team choses not to implement this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13848), but a summary would be:

> The [...] error is by design because for a type parameter T extends C, T is assignable to C, but C is not assignable to T. In this specific case, a GenericSubValue is not assignable to a Partial because the actual type substituted for TValueSub might have properties that are further derived than those in GenericSubValue.

So for example if we have a field, the field can be of a more specialized type, and so the value we asume is valid for `T` might actually not be:

```
function test<T extends { foo: string }>(c: (p: Partial<T>) => void) : void {
    c({
        foo: "" // foo can be string but can be a more specialized type, such as a string literal type
    })
}

// This needs to works, but since foo is more specialized, test can't know what a valid value for Partial<T> is 
test<{ foo: 'just this value'}>(c=> {});
```

The simplest solution, if you want to do this (and have potentially have the class not work correctly for all derived types) is to use a type assertion:

```
public myMethod(): void {
    const items: IListItem<TItem>[] = [];
    this.setState({
        items,
    } as Partial<TState>);
}
```