# Extend a generic class with generic interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to extend a generic class with a generic interface, but I cannot compile it when I try to set the values.

```
interface BaseResultModel {
    name: string;
}
interface BaseResult<T> {
    models: T[];
    group: string;
}

class ResultPage<T extends BaseResult<V>, V extends BaseResultModel> {
    results: T;

    constructor() {
        T = {group: "group1", results: []};
    }
}
```

I cannot set the `results` to empty array.

Comment: I just answered a question with the exact same root cause here, that one uses mapped types, but the same idea applies if you look at the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149173/confusing-typescript-error-using-generic-types/51149331#51149331

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir then I run into https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-object-literal-type-assertion/, right now I disabled it, but do you have any suggesions for this lint error?